# using sed to get a number within a string with parentheses

Tags: bash, sed, html-parsing

I want to get numbers of a website using a bash script. I first wget the webpage and then try to parse the page and get the numbers.

index.html has a long line containing the number I want.

```
(...) </dl><dl class=""><dt>Year <dd>   <a title="City" href="http://example.com/City">City</a> <em>(400)</em>  </dd><dd> (...)
```

I want to get the **400** within the example above. I'm executing the following but is does not make a match:

```
CITYNUMBER=`sed -n -e 's/.*City<\/a>\s<em>(\(.*?\))<\/em>/\1/p' index.html`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n -e 's/.*City<\/a>\s<em>(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p' index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

sed regex is always greedy, so `.*?` won't work anyway

in fact, if you just want to extract the number, grep is good choice:

```
grep -Po 'City</a>\s*<em>\(\K\d*(?=\))'
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo '(...) </dl><dl class=""><dt>Year <dd>   <a title="City" href="http://example.com/City">City</a> <em>(400)</em>  </dd><dd> (...)'|grep -Po 'City</a>\s*<em>\(\K\d*(?=\))'
400
```